# "Antiforgery token could not be decrypted" when trying to connect to SMTP server in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email, mailkit, antiforgerytoken

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web application. I'm attempting to send an email whenever users fill out my contact form. I'm using MailKit to send emails and trying to connect to a NameCheap (Private Email) SMTP email server. I keep getting the error:

```
022-01-05T21:33:53.7036238-06:00 800023e1-0c0e-a700-b63f-84710c7967bb [ERR] An exception was thrown while deserializing the token. (348bf365)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {56726e51-68ea-4ae3-ac4d-13a488d4f33e} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)
2022-01-05T21:34:26.6022697-06:00 80002108-0804-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb [ERR] System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. 66.29.159.53:587
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at MailKit.Net.SocketUtils.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, IPEndPoint localEndPoint, Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MailKit.Net.SocketUtils.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, IPEndPoint localEndPoint, Int32 timeout, Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MailKit.MailService.ConnectNetwork(String host, Int32 port, Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Connect(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Portfolio.Controllers.HomeController.Message(FormModel formObj) in C:\Users\ethan\source\repos\Portfolio\Portfolio\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 340 (1462bf77)
```

I've already contacted NameCheap customer support, and the host and port are correct, so I'm not sure what the problem could be.

My code:

```
                var email = new MimeMessage();
                email.From.Add(new MailboxAddress([Sender Name], "[Sender Email]"));
                email.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("[Receiver Name]", "[Receiver Email]"));

                email.Subject = "Message from: " + [@Model.Name];
                var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
                bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = "<b>Name: </b>" + [@Model.Name] + "<br/>"
                        + "<b>Email: </b>" + [@Model.Email] + "<br/>"
                        + "<b>Message:</b>" + "<br/>" + [@Model.Message];
                email.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

                var client = new SmtpClient();

                try
                {
                    client.Connect([Host], 587, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                    client.Authenticate([Sender Email], [Sender Password]);
                    client.Send(email);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
                    _logger.LogError("Email Sent = [Name: " + [@Model.Name] + "], "
                        + "[Email: " + [@Model.Email] + "], "
                        + "[Message: " + [@Model.Message] + "]");
                }
                finally
                {
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                    client.Dispose();
                }
```

Comment: In my opinion,  this action has thrown two error one is `An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. 66.29.159.53:587`.  I suggest you could firstly make sure your visual studio has running by the admin role and make sure it has enough permission to create the socket connection.

Comment: Yea, it looks like connecting to the mail server IP address/port is failing due to a permissions issue. The Antiforgery token may or may not be related to the permissions problem (I've never seen that before so I'm not sure what it is - maybe some sort of ASP.NET security layer that manages socket permissions?).

Comment: @BrandoZhang When running the application on my local machine, I have no problem sending emails. This issue occurs when I upload the files to HostGator and attempt to use the application in the production environment. That error says that my email server is blocking the connection, so I'm wondering why my hosted application doesn't have permission to access that port

Comment: Could you please tell me if you don't upload the files to HostGator will this issue still happened?

Comment: @BrandoZhang Yes, the issue occurred only in my hosted instance on HostGator, not in my local environment. After spending 4-5 days trying to fix the authorization issue, I ended up using the SendGrid API to send emails instead of using SMTP to connect to my mail server, and I'm now able to send emails